# Find string between quotes, addClass to this.string and hide quotes

Tags: jquery, string, quotes

**So** everything is in the question.

In a RSS Flux, I have some texte. I need to find a string between quote.

exemple:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("div.esg-bottom").each(function() {
    var jQuery(this).text() = s.match(/"(.*?)"/);
    jQuery(this).text(): addClass('toto');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="esg-bottom eg-post-590 eg-mouveat-fb-element-2">Santé"Les additifs, un réel problème sanitaire"Voici une petite vidéo tournée dans des écoles en Australie. L'Australie pays du paradoxe avec un taux d'obésité record et des mauvaises habitudes alimentaires...</div>
```

But sure it fails ;)

Any help would be greatfull

Comment: You can't add a class to a text node.  You would need to put it in a span or something, and put a class on that

Comment: <div class="esg-bottom eg-post-590 eg-mouveat-fb-element-2">Santé"Les additifs, un réel problème sanitaire"Voici une petite vidéo tournée dans des écoles en Australie. L'Australie pays du paradoxe avec un taux d'obésité record et des mauvaises habitudes alimentaires...</div>

Comment: OK for span, but how to 'catch' spécific string beetween quotes?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the replace method to inject the span with the class on it.

```js
$('#testing').html(function(index, value){
  return value.replace(/"([^"]+)"/, function(_, match1){
    return "<span class='toto'>"+ match1 +"</span>";
  });
});
```

```css
.toto { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="testing">
Santé"Les additifs, un réel problème sanitaire"Voici une petite vidéo tournée dans des écoles en Australie". L'Australie pays du paradoxe avec un taux d'obésité record et des mauvaises habitudes alimentaires... 
</div>
```

Comment: This does not answer the question as asked i.e. for the selector `"div.esg-bottom"`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Change the id to a class, change the selector to match, both approaches work with this logic.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a span that has that class perhaps?

```js
$(function() {
  $("div.esg-bottom").each(function() {
    let t = $(this).text();
    var regex = /(".*\")+/g
    var s = t.replace(regex, function(m) {
      return '<span class="toto">' + m + '</span>';
    });
    $(this).html(s);
  });
});
```

```css
.toto{color:blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="esg-bottom eg-post-590 eg-mouveat-fb-element-2">Santé"Les additifs, un réel problème sanitaire"Voici une petite vidéo tournée dans des écoles en Australie. L'Australie pays du paradoxe avec un taux d'obésité record et des mauvaises habitudes alimentaires...outside quotes</div>
<div class="esg-bottom eg-post-590 eg-mouveat-fb-element-2">Cheese "I like blue cheese. " my cheese is not outside quotes</div>
```

Comment: Thank all, your solution works,

but a last question for a second page: I have       

<p class="cff-post-text"><span class="cff-text" data-color=""><b style="font-size: 22px">"Les additifs, un réel problème sanitaire"</b><br> <br> Voici une petite vidéo tournée dans des écoles en Australie. L'Australie ... </span><span class="cff-expand" style="display: inline;">... <a href="#" style="color: #"><span class="cff-more">See More</span><span class="cff-less">See Less</span></a></span></p>

I Need to suppress quotes from <b>"mytitleinaquote"</b> and don't know how to do...

Thanks for help

Comment: That is a NEW question.  Please ask a NEW question rather than changing the original question context and requirements